# How to create a regex that accepts specific characters?

Tags: java, android, regex

I have this regex:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.#$%&'*+-/=?^`{|}~!(),:;<>[-\]]{8,}$
```

I need a regex to accept a minimum word length of 8, letters(uppercase & lowercase), numbers and these characters:

!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~"(),:;<>@[]

It works when I tested it [here](https://www.regextester.com/).

This is how I used it in Java Android.

```
public static final String regex = "^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.#$%&'*+-/=?^`{|}~!(),:;<>[-\\]]{8,}$";
```

This is the error that I received.

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Missing closing bracket in character class near index 49
    ^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.#$%&'*+-/=?^`{|}~!(),:;<>[-\]]{8,}$
```

Comment: You need to use `Pattern` class to create a `Pattern` object which you can use to `match` or `find` the data as per your needs.

Comment: I already did that but still fails. This is how I used it. Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

Comment: This is the error that I received.

Missing closing bracket in character class near index 49
    ^[a-zA-Z0-9_@.#$%&'*+-/=?^`{|}~!(),:;<>[-\]]{8,}$

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to test if a given input string matches your pattern, you may use `String#matches` directly, e.g.

```
String regex = "[a-zA-Z0-9_@.#$%&'*+-/=?^`{|}~!(),:;<>\\[\\]-]{8,}";
String input = "Jon@Skeet#123";

if (input.matches(regex)) {
    System.out.println("Found a match");
}
else {
    System.out.println("No match");
}
```

If you wanted to parse a larger input text and identify such matching words, then you would want to use a formal `Pattern` and `Matcher`.  But, I don't see the need for this just based on your question.

Comment: Even your code doesn't work and runs into `PatternSyntaxException` for me. Is it really working at your end? What Java version are you using? I am on Java 8 and if it worked at your end then you must surely be on a higher version like 9 or more.

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi Sorry, the pattern had a slight error, which I have corrected.  I took it on faith that the OP posted a working Java pattern; I guess that wasn't the case.

Comment: Exactly, that was OP's main problem. His regex was running into errors because he didn't escape `[` character in a character class which in most languages doesn't need to be escaped. And escaping `[` character solves the problem but why in Java `[` character needs to be escaped while in most other languages it doesn't have to be? I've known this fact since some time now but couldn't find the reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use pattern marcher concept. it may help you.

follow tutorial : https://www.mkyong.com/regular-expressions/how-to-validate-password-with-regular-expression/

Here is one Example.

```
  try {
                Pattern pattern;
                Matcher matcher;
                final String PASSWORD_PATTERN = "((?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%]).{6,20})";
                pattern = Pattern.compile(PASSWORD_PATTERN);
                matcher = pattern.matcher(password_string );

                 if(matcher.matches()){
                     Log.e("TAG", "TRUE")
                    }else{
                     Log.e("TAG", "FALSE")
                     }

            } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                return false;
            }
```